# VBA Save (Add) Data Duplicate Items on ListBox, but only Save One (as it should)

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform, xlsm

I'm trying to develop a plan, and when I'm saving a item, the listbox add the new item, but duplicates the other data aready saved, duplicating the itens.

```
Salve code: Private Sub btnSalvar_Click()

If txtReceita.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Insira o nome da receita"), vbInformation, "Cadastro de Receitas"
    Exit Sub
End If

If btnModificar.Value = True Then
    nlin = listaReceitas.ListIndex
    If nlin = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Selecione uma receita para editar", vbInformation, "Cadastro de Receitas"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf listaReceitas.Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Selecione uma receita para editar", vbInformation, "Cadastro de Receitas"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call modificar

Else
linha = Sheets("NOMES RECEITAS").Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("NOMES RECEITAS").Cells(linha, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("NOMES RECEITAS").Range("B:B")) + 1
Sheets("NOMES RECEITAS").Cells(linha, 3).Value = txtReceita.Value
    txtReceita.Value = ""
    
MsgBox "Receita adicionada com sucesso!", vbInformation, "Cadastro de Receitas"
    End If
Call Atualizar_Receitas
End Sub
Display ListBox Code: Sub Atualizar_Receitas()

Dim rg As Range
Dim linf As Integer
'Dim wPlan As Worksheet
Dim vLin As Integer
   
    Set wPlan = Planilha10
    vLin = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Planilha10.Range("C:C"))
    Set rg = wPlan.Range("C2:C" & vLin)
    For linf = 1 To rg.Rows.Count
               
        With Me.listaReceitas
            '.ColumnWidths = "45;110;30;95"
            .ColumnCount = 2
            .AddItem
            .List(listaReceitas.ListCount - 1, 1) = rg.Cells(linf, 1)
        End With
    Next
Me.lblContador.Caption = Me.listaReceitas.ListCount & " Receita(s)"
End Sub
```

[image: Plan with all items]

[image: Form when start - showing correct number of items = 11]

[image: Form after saving "new item" - showing duplicate of the others item + the new one, total items = 23, but the plan only have 12 items]

I've watched a lot of videos, but to no success.
I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Is clearing the list an option? `.Clear` before `.ColumnCount = 2`?

Comment: No good. When doing that the ListBox goes empty and only shows the last add item

Comment: My bad. You have to do it before the loop: `Me.listaReceitas.Clear`. Also, the `ColumnCount = 2` should go outside (before) the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by adding +1 at the row count.

```
Sub Atualizar_Receitas()

    On Error GoTo Erro
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim linf As Integer
    
    Dim vLin As Integer
       
        Set wPlan = Planilha10
        vLin = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Planilha10.Range("C:C"))
        Set rg = wPlan.Range("C2:C" & vLin)
        Me.listaReceitas.Clear
        For linf = 1 To rg.Rows.Count + 1
                   
            With Me.listaReceitas
                .ColumnCount = 2
                .AddItem
                .List(listaReceitas.ListCount - 1, 0) = rg.Cells(linf, 0)
                .List(listaReceitas.ListCount - 1, 1) = rg.Cells(linf, 1)
            End With
        Next
    Me.lblContador.Caption = Me.listaReceitas.ListCount & " Receita(s)"
    
    Exit Sub
    Erro:
    MsgBox "Ocorreu um Erro!", vbCritical, "ERRO - ListBox"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).